# Getting order values from functions that run as asyncio tasks

Tags: python, python-asyncio

```
# coding=utf-8
import asyncio
import functools
import time

import requests


def get_url(url):
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36'

    if 'bing' in url:
        time.sleep(5)

    a = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    return a


async def crawler(url):
    print('Start crawling:', url)
 
    future = asyncio.get_event_loop().run_in_executor(None, functools.partial(get_url, url))

    response = await future

    print('Response received:', url, response.status_code)
    return url


tasks = [
    asyncio.Task(crawler("https://www.bing.com")),
    asyncio.Task(crawler("https://www.sogou.com")),
    asyncio.Task(crawler("https://www.baidu.com")),
]

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
result = loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(tasks))
    
for i in result[0]:
    print(i.result())
```

Because it will sleep 5s on bing.com , so
I got result like this:

```
https://www.sogou.com
https://www.baidu.com
https://www.bing.com
```

This order is depend on when they completed.
How can i get the result order by when it start?
so in some case I can Splicing the result

expected order

```
https://www.bing.com
https://www.sogou.com
https://www.baidu.com
```

Comment: You want to use `asyncio.gather` instead of `asyncio.wait`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary and add a new key for each URL when the task is entered. Add the responses to the dictionary itself. To ensure order, it is better to add the keys to the dictionary in sync code. (This is possible because in newer Python's, dict is ordered by default - in older versions one would need to use `collections.OrderedDict` for a similar use)

```py
# coding=utf-8
import asyncio
import functools
import time

import requests


def get_url(url):
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36'
    }

    if 'bing' in url:
        time.sleep(5)

    a = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    return a


async def crawler(url):
    print('Start crawling:', url)

    future = asyncio.get_event_loop().run_in_executor(None, functools.partial(get_url, url))

    response = await future

    print('Response received:', url, response.status_code)
    results[url] = (response.status_code, url)
    return url

results = {}
def ordered_result(url):
    # Sync function: ensure the ordered created of the dictionary keys

    # 'results' used from toplvel
    results[url] = None

    # By not creating a task, co-routine execution start is delayied:
    return crawler(url)


tasks = [
    ordered_result("https://www.bing.com"),
    ordered_result("https://www.sogou.com"),
    ordered_result("https://www.baidu.com")
]

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

# Ordered return values are anotated inside the co-routine itself.
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*tasks))

for r in results.values():
    print(r)
```

Comment: Or just use `gather` (as already suggested in a comment to the question) which does all that work for you.

Comment: Oh yes-  gather by itself already preserves the order. As I had never needed the ordered results, I forgot it had this additional feature;